# OneNote - export all sections in a notebook to Word? Or other method for same result

Tags: microsoft-onenote-2010

I have a OneNote 2010 notebook with a lot of sections (and some of those sections have lots of pages.) **What I'd like to do is a get a good, space-saving printout (with minimal whitespace) to take physical notes on when I'm in meetings AFK, or brainstorming old-school.**

I don't want to just print all sections and pages, because there's a lot of whitespace (I do have some pages with just one or two lines), and there's some pages I want to exclude. Thus, it looks like I want to export to Word, and then manually remove some sections and also manually remove page-breaks, to tighten things up and not waste (as much) paper.

However, you can only save an entire notebook as ONEPKG, PDF, or XPS. I only have Adobe Reader, and I don't know if full-version Adobe would let me remove pagebreaks, it's not that kind of editor, AFAIK - rather, PDF isn't that kind of format. XPS is also just a display format, again AFAIK. I could save each individual section as a DOC, and then Import Text from File for each DOC into a new blank one, doing it in the proper order and removing the content I don't want as I go. (I did this once. It's not terrible, but somewhat a PITA.)

Is there a plugin or technique to do one of :

1. An easy way to save an entire notebook to a single DOC?
2. An easy way to automate saving all sections in a notebook to individual DOCs, without doing it one-by-one manually?
3. Any other way to go about this? Some kind of whitespace-chewing pretty-printer for OneNote?

I'm not much of a VB/VBA guy, so answers that suggest I script this will give me a sad, unless they're written for not-so-bright young children.

Comment: This answer might help you: https://superuser.com/a/1532862/318896

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first alternative, with better results, is to use [One Note PowerShell with the explanation given in this blog](http://bdewey.com/2007/07/18/onenote-powershell-provider/) to export all pages changed after a specific date (*hum... let's say... pages created after 01-01-1970*) as one single .mht file, then edit that file in your Word.

There's also the [OneNote Power Toys](http://www.onenotepowertoys.com/2007/08/23/merge-pages-powertoy/) that can be used to merge pages in One Note...

The [OneNote to HTML Server](http://code.google.com/p/one2htm/) allows you to save one html for each page that is changed in a One Note directory, and if you change them all, you'll have a one-html-per-page. The problem is to make a little change in every page.

And, finally, the [One Note Web Exporter](http://onwebber.codeplex.com/) creates a web page that you can use inside any browser. But it won't be a single, continous HTML, it will resamble your OneNote page-separation. Perhaps easy to edit the resulting web-page to make it a single html, but I'm not sure.

Comment: This is a really useful set of tools - thank you.

Answer (score 2):

@xtianman hinted at this so I tried just shift-click and selecting all pages in a section (I have about 40 in the one I needed).
After shift-click to select all pages along the right, I used cmd-c (apple copy to buffer), then just cmd-v to paste all pages into word. To my surprise, it actually worked! All pages pasted into word (the word document is 158 pages after everything pasted).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how big the notebook is but you can `control+click` and `shift+click` while in a notebook to select specific pages (located on the right pane) you want and then goto `save as -> page ->` and select the format, `.doc`, `.docx`, etc. This effectively exports the pages that you want and leaving the others in the notebook.

Comment: This doesn't work across multiple sections.

Comment: I thought the idea was to export pages into individual files.

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking for a solution to this tread as well but i finally found the solution!!
Using mac; just use the shift click to highlight everything you want to export, click on edit and do copy, then go to ms word and paste, it will paste everything from the page!, note for copying all the pages of a page not for a section.

Comment: Would that not be tedious work to select content from each and every page within each section?

Comment: Fairly useless answer, since that's even more manual work than some of the things that I outlined in my question as existing stop-gap methods. It's also not exclusive to MacOS.

Comment: Lol am I getting a negative reaction, I just had to create this account to tell people what I found, I have to block this from my mail, yes my English suck and might not be easy to understand. @ Prasanna and mfinni what I'm saying is to highlight all the pages of a sections on the right hand side, copy and paste to ms-word, meaning you will have all the content (pages) of one section but not all the sections at once. If you have up to 15 sections like in my case, then you will repeat the same process 15 times which is not tedious to me.

Comment: And please; I don't know what this site is all about but I found myself here because I was looking for a solutions to my problem not because I'm looking for someone that I will answer their problems, if it doesn't help u leave it for those it might help .

Comment: If you don't know what this site is about, there's a very handy "help" link at the top with years'-worth of FAQ.