# Automated export from Microsoft OneNote to multiple file formats

Tags: export, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2013

I have more than 1 GB of OneNote files. I would like to automatically export each of my over 150 notebooks to a Microsoft Word document, a single Web Page file and a PDF file.

Microsoft OneNote will only let me export one notebook at a time, at most, and it can't even be to a Word File.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: You could merge all your notebooks into a single file then convert that file in a single swoop

Comment: Do you have any idea on how i can merge all the 150 onenote notebooks into one single onenote notebook ?   Thanks

Comment: Similar thread on SuperUser and some answers:

http://superuser.com/questions/389879/onenote-export-all-sections-in-a-notebook-to-word-or-other-method-for-same-re

Answer (score -1):

Try this tool:

[one note 2 pdf on codeplex](https://onenote2pdf.codeplex.com/)