# How can I export all OneNote pages to individual markdown files?

Tags: export, microsoft-onenote, markdown, microsoft-onenote-2016

I am moving to Linux and the last hurdle is to get out of OneNote. I'd like to export all of my notebooks so that every page goes to an individual markdown file.

I've tried many things—[this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/389879/onenote-export-all-sections-in-a-notebook-to-word-or-other-method-for-same-re) had several suggestions, but they are all outdated.

If I could get OneNote to export all of the pages as individual .docx files, it would be easy to use pandoc to convert them to individual markdown files. But, OneNote will only export multiple pages as a single file. So, one route would be to find a way to automate the export of every single page individually.

Another option is to export entire notebooks at a time as .docx files, convert them to markdown with pandoc, and then split the files—but, I am not enough of a regex wizard to get csplit to cut the files correctly with just its basic regular expressions, and not enough of an awk wizard to get it to output files with the correct and full regular expression.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 17):

I did end up finding an export pipeline, but it was a pain. Here are my notes from doing that:

**workflow:**

1. Turn off your network(s) to prevent OneNote from performing a lengthy OneDrive sync after each export.
2. In the Notebooks list, expand the notebook to see all the tabs.
3. Right click a tab and click "Export...".
4. Click the filetype dropdown and press <kbd>M</kbd> to select `.docx` format. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select it.
5. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again to save the exported file.
6. Repeat steps 2-5 for each tab in the notebook.
7. Set up pandoc and open a PowerShell or cmd window.
8. cd into the directory where the exported `.docx` files are located.
9. For each exported `.docx` file, use the following pandoc command to convert it to markdown (replace `journal` with the name of your file):

   ```
   pandoc --extract-media='' --wrap=preserve '.\journal.docx' -o journal.md
   ```

   Here's an explanation of the command: `--extract-media=''` tells pandoc to extract images from the `.docx` file and put them in the default subfolder (named 'media' by default). `--wrap=preserve` tells pandoc not hard-wrap the output file with linebreaks (which is the default). The next field is the input filename, and `-o` stands for 'output', so `journal.md` is the output filename.

   If you don't want to split this file (for example, if your tab contained only one page), skip to step 15.

   (When you are doing a bunch of these, you can press the <kbd>↑</kbd> (up arrow) key to recall the previous command in the shell, then edit the filename.)
10. Create a new folder to store the pages in the tab. For this example, right now all the pages from our Journal tab in OneNote are mashed together in `journal.md`. Make a folder called `journal` which will store the final separated pages as individual .md files.
11. If there were any images in the `.docx` file, these will be exported to a new folder called `media`. Drag the media folder, if it exists, into the folder you just created now. (This is why we need to do each pandoc operation seperately, because each export will create a separate media folder, and we want to keep these separate so the links in the markdown files work correctly. We could write a clever script to do all this automatically, but it will take less time to just do it manually, unless you have a huge number of notebooks.) (Note: You can save a step by putting your desired foldername in the single quotes of the `--extract-media=''` argument—for `.docx` files with images, a folder will be created automatically for you.)
12. Open a bash terminal and cd to the directory containing the `.md` file. The folder you created in step 10 must be a subfolder of this one (unless you fix the path in the following command).
13. If you haven't already, click the Windows Bash window icon, click on Properties, check QuickEdit Mode, then click OK. Now click on the Windows Bash window icon again, this time click on Defaults, check QuickEdit Mode, and then click OK (so new Bash windows you create in the future will remember this setting).
    Now you can select text in the terminal and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy, or right-click the terminal window to paste the text into the clipboard. Now we can prepare our command in a separate location, and quickly paste each version into Bash.
14. Customize the following command and run it for each `.md` file you want to split into individual pages:

    `csplit ./journal.md --keep-files --prefix='journal/journalentry ' 
    --suffix-format='%i.md' --elide-empty-files '/^\(Monday\|Tuesday\|Wednesday\|Thursday\|Friday\|Saturday\|Sunday\),/-2' '{*}'`

    (Type it as one line.)

    As you can see, `journal.md` is the name of our markdown file (in the current directory, denoted by `./`), the second occurrence of `journal` (after `--prefix='`) is the name of our subfolder which will contain the split files, and `journalentry` is what each file will be named (followed by an index number).

    If you want to understand the command, here's an explanation: `--keep-files` still prints files when errors or the end of the file is encountered, ensuring the last page will be output correctly (since it doesn't end in the pattern of our regular expression). `--prefix` sets the naming scheme of the output files. `--suffix-format` allows us to set our file extension (`.md` in this case), but we must include `%i` for the sprintf statement which outputs the index number of the file.  `--elide-empty-files` skips outputting empty files, which we don't care about. Finally, the regular expression, which begins with `'/` and ends with `/-2'`, defines when to split the file: it says "When you find (/) at the start of the line (^) the following (() Monday or (\|) Tuesday or Wednesday or Thursday or Friday or Saturday or Sunday ()) followed by a comma, step back two lines (-2)" and split the file there, outputting what we have up until now. The final bit, `'{*}'`, repeats the previous command indefinitely, until the end of the file is reached.
15. Drag the `.docx` and `.md` files into a folder, say a folder you create now called `intermediates`. Or you can just delete them. It's nice to save them for a while, until you are comfortable with your new file format, in case you want to go back and reference something that happened during the conversion process. Moving them into the intermediates folder now will rude  the chance of forgetting where we are and repeating steps.
16. Repeat steps 9-14 for each `.docx` file you exported from OneNote.
17. Now you have one folder for each tab, with a bunch of separate `.md` files in it, one for each page! Plus a `media` folder in each subfolder that had images in the OneNote tab.
18. I recommend exporting each of your OneNote notebooks as a `.mht` file (Single File Web Page), or, if you prefer, a `.pdf`. This way, if there was lost formatting or other information in some of your markdown files, due to the multiple conversion, you can always go back and easily see how it was supposed to look in the `.mht` file. In addition, I would recommend exporting each of your OneNote notebooks as a `.onepkg` file (OneNote Package), so you have a nice final export copy if you ever want to reopen the Notebook in OneNote in its native/original file format (this might be useful if, for example, the `.mht` file is also missing some original formatting that you want to recover).
19. As you finish each notebook, right-click the notebook in OneNote and click "Close This Notebook" so you won't accidentally edit the notebook and have to re-export your new changes. For the markdown folders, I also created a folder for each notebook, and put all the tab folders in it.
20. When you are finished with the whole export project, you can go to your OneDrive and delete all your OneNote notebooks originals which have synced there (make sure you are backing up your own files now, of course! There is OneDrive for Linux, or you could try something like Syncthing).
21. Finally, we can rename all our .md files to their OneNote page title, which is the first line in each file, by using two scripts. Make the following files:

    File 1: `~/scripts/rename-files-to-first-line.sh`

    ```
    for i in *md ; do mv -n "$i" "$(cat "$i"|head -n1|tr -d '\000-\037[]{}()/\?*')".md; done
    ```

    File 2: `~/scripts/recurse.sh`

    ```
    CDIR=$(pwd)
    for i in $(ls -R | grep :); do
        DIR=${i%:}                    # Strip ':'
        cd $DIR
        $1                            # Your command
        cd $CDIR
    done
    ```

    Then navigate to your notes folder and run the `recurse.sh` command using the `rename-files-to-first-line.sh` command as an argument:

    ```
    $ ~/scripts/recurse.sh ~/scripts/rename-files-to-first-line.sh
    ```

    You will see the script go through all your files recursively, throwing some errors on files with weird first lines (that won't convert to a filename) and on other edge cases. However, the `mv` command in `rename-files-to-first-line` is executed with argument `-n`, which will prevent it from overwriting any files. There might be a few notes that don't get renamed, because the first line in them is blank or something else weird, but you can just fix those few files manually.
22. Bask in your clean escape from OneNote.

Caveats:

- This doesn't capture subpages—you will have to recreate those with sub-subfolders, if you like.
- I don't know how well it does with tables—markdown is a bit ungainly for tables anyway.
- There are probably other kinds of formatting, such as fonts, which get lost or screwed up in the export. But for rich text and images, it works pretty well!

Comment: Won't work if you have attachments in OneNote

Comment: Wow, what a mess. I should have never started taking notes with this software. Thanks for writing all this down! Note that as of today, there still is no export feature for OneNote under macOS.

Comment: Has anyone tried to import the resulting MD files from this into Notion? did it work?

Comment: Also this is not realistic if you have hundreds of pages in a notebook section each one with a unique title, only works if you have a the specific naming style OP have used. I do appreciate the effort though.

Answer (score 10):

The other answer didn't cut it for me, because my notes are not journal entries, but I found a solution using [Microsoft's Graph API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onenote-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0). This means you don't even have to run OneNote, it just requires that your notes are synced to your Microsoft account and then you can get your notes as perfectly formatted HTML (which you can view in the browser or convert to whatever format you prefer using Pandoc).

The magic happens in [this Python script](https://gist.github.com/Danmou/46e21b0c7090cb27425fa389f5102b16). It runs a simple local web server that you can use to log in to your Microsoft account and once you do that it downloads all your notes as HTML, plus images and attachments in their original formats, and stores them in file hierarchy preserving the original structure of your notebooks (including page order and subpages).

Before you can run the script, you have to register an "app" in Microsoft Azure so it can access the Graph API:

1. Go to https://aad.portal.azure.com/ and log in with your Microsoft account.
2. Select "Azure Active Directory" and then "App registrations" under "Manage".
3. Select "New registration". Choose any name, set "Supported account types" to "Accounts in any organizational directory and personal Microsoft accounts" and under "Redirect URI", select Web and enter `http://localhost:5000/getToken`. Register.
4. Copy the "Application (client) ID" and paste it as `client_id` in the beginning of the Python script.
5. Select "Certificates & secrets" under "Manage". Press "New client secret", choose a name and confirm.
6. Copy the client secret and paste it as `secret` in the Python script.
7. Select "API permissions" under "Manage". Press "Add a permission", scroll down and select OneNote, choose "Delegated permissions" and check "Notes.Read" and "Notes.Read.All". Press "Add permissions".

Then you need to install the Python dependencies. Make sure you have Python 3.7 (or newer) installed and install the dependencies using the command `pip install flask msal requests_oauthlib`.

Now you can run the script. In a terminal, navigate to the directory where the script is located and run it using `python onenote_export.py`. This will start a local web server on port 5000.

In your browser navigate to http://localhost:5000 and log in to your Microsoft account. The first time you do it, you will also have to accept that the app can read your OneNote notes. (This does not give any third parties access to your data, as long as you don't share the client id and secret you created on the Azure portal). After this, go back to the terminal to follow the progress.

Note: Microsoft limits how many requests you can do within a given time period. Therefore, if you have many notes you might eventually see messages like this in the terminal: `Too many requests, waiting 20s and trying again.` This is not a problem, but it means the entire process can take a while. Also, the login session can expire after a while, which results in a `TokenExpiredError`. If this happens, simply reload http://localhost:5000 and the script will continue (skipping the files it already downloaded).

Comment: Good simpler solution, But this gets the files in HTML, not MD

Comment: As I briefly mentioned in the answer, you can use pandoc to convert HTML to markdown (e.g. `pandoc --from html --to markdown -o output.md input.html`). However, it should be noted that not all OneNote pages can be represented perfectly in markdown so you might lose some formatting details. Also, pandoc supports several flavours of markdown so you might want to read the documentation to find one that suits your use.

Comment: Ok certainly worth a try before taking the long route in the first answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

To export your OneNote pages to individual markdown (`.md`) you should install [Joplin](https://joplinapp.org/) and [Evernote](https://evernote.com).

As suggested in this [link](https://joplinapp.org/#importing-from-other-applications), first you import the notes into Evernote. Then export all the notes into a `.enex` file from Evernote and import them into Joplin.

Joplin has the option to export the notes as `.md` files.

Note: I suggest using flags in Evernote beforehand if you want to group your notes, since the Evernote way to keep hierarchy between notes is different from OneNote.

Comment: You are awesome! Your answer inspired me to import notebook sections into Evernote, then import them from Evernote into Notion! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Finally, someone has resolved this for once and for all. All the above methods might work, but have pro's and cons. Migrating through Evernote and then Notion or Jotterpad, or manually doing it through exporting as .mht or .xps files and then to .html, and then to markdown all has the drawback that 'complex' Onenote pages won't be copied in a workable way: if you have an image somewhere random on the page, your whole Markdown file will be a table, and working in it will be hell.

SjoerdV has written a Powershell script you can run, which will export all the workbooks you have open for you to a .docx document, and then convert it all into Markdown, keeping your whole file hierarchy, keeping images, everything! You can find it here: https://github.com/SjoerdV/ConvertOneNote2MarkDown

All you have to do: clone the repository (or get the .ps1 file (powershell script) from github), go to the commandline and to the directory where you've got that .ps1 file, run it (type `.\ConvertOneNote2MarkDown.ps1`), provide the full directory path where you wish to drop the files, and it starts running for you.

Don't forget to thank the original author for helping you out of your Onenote lock-in!

*Drawback: only works on Windows...*

Edit: forgot to add the link

Comment: Which following author? Your post lacks information required to make it an answer

Comment: @music2myear excuse me, forgot to add the link. Classic. If you find it useful, could you change yourdownvote?

Comment: @music2myear kind reminder, does this post now qualify as an answer?

Comment: You should have said Joplin instead of Jotterpad, nobody mentioned that software. I don't understand why people avoid suggesting open source software like Joplin.

Comment: Even though this solution may be viable it's important to note that you require to take print-screens of every ink annotation which is comber-some: "Because OneNote does not have this function you will have to take screenshots of your pages with pen/hand written notes and paste the resulting image and then remove the scriblings."

Comment: @bruno ah yes, this solution does not support handwritten notes in Onenote, but that was never a requirement of OP. I think handwitten notes are a bit beyond scope of the discussion at hand here, as you would have this problem for (I think) all ways to export notes from onenote to markdown, unless you'd use some OCR technology

Comment: Hi, just wanted to share that I was able to run this script on my Mac M1 using Parallels and setting up a Windows environment.  It was a fair amount of effort but it is possible.

Answer (score 3):

I developped a Windows Console Application that can export a OneNote notebooks in markdown format. You can have a look here : https://github.com/alxnbl/onenote-md-exporter .

Hope it can help.

Comment: OP is asking how to export individual OneNote pages to markdown files. Also, explaining HOW to use your tool would make this more than the advertising spam it currently appears to be.

Comment: Thank you for posting the link. Please consider to extend your posting by describing a little bit necessary requirements, outcomes and possible limitations. Thank you!

Comment: Works very nicely. +1

Answer (score 1):

I have a found a non programmatic work around for this.

TLDR;

Export notes from OneNote into [Evernote](https://www.evernote.com/) then into [Notion](https://www.notion.so/) (Optional) then export as individual files with a format of your choice.

---

I've been really struggling to export my notes from Notion, a look online will return some really unclean ways to export & split OneNote pages and turn them into md or html files. What a mess!

Basically you can very easily import your OneNote sections into Evernote, after downloading Evernote for desktop it's quite easy to do that, then from there, it's also equally easy to import those into Notion.

Just be aware, you might want to import individual sections if you want to keep the same organization, otherwise you could just bulk import all of the sections, pages will be tagged with the section names and that's all the way into Notion as well.

Please note you'll need to have synced your OneNote notebooks by logging in to your Microsoft/Outlook account and verifying they are synced using OneNote 2016.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I found was using this script: https://github.com/theohbrothers/ConvertOneNote2MarkDown.

I was able to run this on my Mac M1 by using using Parallels to setup a windows environment with Onenote and MS Word installed.

I spent a lot of effort on this recently and tried a bunch of different approaches and this seemed to be the only way to achieve it.  It requires a fair amount of time and technical abilities.

Answer (score 1):

well, it took me 2 days to find a comfortable 100% working way thanks to [Joplin](https://joplinapp.org/) app which seems to be replacing OneNote for me now. There is a wonderful GH user https://github.com/alxnbl who created the converter from OneNote to MD files or Joplin export files. The project resides here: https://github.com/alxnbl/onenote-md-exporter.

All you need is Windows and OneNote running. The converter will extract all data directly from the running app and then save wither to MD files or to Joplin raw export.

I hope it'll save a lot of time and web surfing to the people trying to walk away from MS products.

cheers

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1237063)

Answer (score 0):

I tried most of the suggestions above, but they are either too time consuming or require a doctorate degree to complete.

I ended up using Notejoy.com (signed up for a month to do the conversions). Export from OneNote (had to remove all sound attachments) and import to Notejoy. Then export all the notes to Google Drive (remember to not export excessive amounts > 250). Download all docs in a zip with their individual folders (first structure of OneNote). Download the docs as docx files and unzip them. Import one and one of the folders to have at least the top level sorting of folders in Notion. Rename import to the folder name.

What's left after the import is to go through the notes and add them under other notes if you used the second and third hierarchy in OneNote. It's a bit messy, but should take little time compared to exporting and importing individual pages manually.