# How to export the whole Section Group from OneNote?

Tags: microsoft-onenote

I want to export the whole Section Group, and sent it to my friend. My Section Group has many sections, I do not want to export each of them one by one.

There is an "Export" function in OneNote, but I can only export one section, not the whole Section Group. Why is that? I feel that I could not actually highlight the Section Group, I can only highlight a section

[image]

Comment: See this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/412049/383350)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new temporary notebook, copy the section group to the new notebook. Now your new notebook contains only 1 section group with many sections.

Then export this temporary notebook.

Comment: Depending on your organization method, it might be worth considering moving the section group to a new Notebook anyway.

Comment: Update for OneNote 2016: I could only move the section group to a new notebook, not copy. Once moved, I exported the entire new notebook to a package, moved the section group back to the original notebook, then imported the package in the notebook where I wanted it.